# How to add menu items to WebKitContextMenu (javascript, gjs)?

Tags: gtk, gjs, webkitgtk

When I try to add menuitems to a webview with this code:

```
my_webview.connect('context-menu', Lang.bind(this, function(webview, c_menu, event, hit_test){
      var action = new Gtk.Action({name:"some_name", label:"Some Label"});
      action.connect('activate', Lang.bind(this, function(){
          print("Your Menu Item !");
      }))

      var m_item = new WebKit.ContextMenuItem(action);
      c_menu.append(m_item);
      m_item.show();
      return false;
  }));
```

the app exit with the error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"
What's the correct way to add a menuitem to the context menu of a WebView ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Small correction:

```
var m_item = WebKit.ContextMenuItem.new(action);
```

This is confusing to say the least, it's because `WebKit.ContextMenuItem` has a custom constructor and not the usual GObject constructor that would be invoked with `new WebKit.ContextMenuItem`. The segmentation fault is due to WebKit choking when its context menu item doesn't receive an action; however, it would be good if GJS at least warned you what was going on here.

I've opened a bug report for GJS [here](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=774663).